# Magento 2: Override Magento_Payment::info/default.phtml

Tags: magento2, template

What is the best way to Override `Magento_Payment::info/default.phtml` in module ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Inside a custom theme would be the best approach to override this template.

***LE:*** In a custom module there are several ways you could try this, check [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#set_template) the instructions from devdocs for *Setting the template used by a block*.

Comment: I am not using theme, just using a module is their any way i can override with in the module ? That would be great

Comment: I updated my answer :)

Comment: Thankyou i will try & update.

Comment: roger that, please let me know the results.

Comment: Hello,

Template file - Magento_Payment::info/default.phtml

Block - Magento2/vendor/magento/module-payment/Block/Info.php

The template file is declared in info.php, i have tried with plugin "beforeToHtml" & set module's template but didn't work.

Comment: hmm, ok. i'll come back at you if i have another idea on how to do this, there should be a way :D

Comment: Sure & yup i believe there should be a way, Thanks

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?