# Magento 2 : Override template file /info/default.phtml

Tags: magento2, template

How to override below file in module ?

```
Magento2/vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/templates/info/default.phtml
```

Comment: The file from which is called is vendor/magento/module-payment/Block/Info.php

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Hi, what is your actual requirement to override this?

Comment: Hello, as there is some design issue in payment section in order email template, i have checked & found that this file is used to render the payment method data in email confirmation.
i have added some styles & tried to override this default.phtml file in module.
but it does not seems to be working.

Comment: If you want to add style then it is not a proper way. You can add style from admin. You just need to load email template in admin. You need to write style there for particular template.

Comment: Thankyou @ZealousWeb, this sounds like a good idea.
i will check it.

Comment: Here you can add style - https://prnt.sc/10hspo5, you just need to select newly added template for order email from stores > configuration > sales > sales emails

Comment: Thanks for the reference,
can i ask you from where the giftcard items data render in order confirmation email template ?

Actually i am trying to customize order confirmation email template, it works for other product types except gift.

Comment: Here you can find gift card items render - vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120690/discussion-between-devhs-and-zealousweb).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento 2: Override Magento\_Payment::info/default.phtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/331885/magento-2-override-magento-paymentinfo-default-phtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below way.

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Payment\Block\Info">
        <plugin name="module_paympent_view_override_template" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Payment\Block\Info" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Info.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Payment\Block;
 
class Info
{
    public function beforeToHtml(\Magento\Payment\Block\Info $subject)
    {        
            $subject->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::info/default.phtml');        
    }
}
```

The above code is not tested. I have just shared the way to override.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will check this answer.

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Vendor_Sales::info/default.phtml' in module: 'Magento_OfflinePayments' block's name: 'info\checkmo_0'

Comment: This error appeared

Comment: can you please explain what your answer actually does ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: U r Welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's so easy. You need to copy that file into your vendor theme in app/desing.
So, the original path file is `vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/templates/info/default.phtml`, you need to copy and paste it in `app/design/MyVendor/MyTheme/Magento_Payment/templates/info/default.phtml`.

After this flush magento cache.

Answer (score 0):

1)Create di.xml file and add following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="module_paympent_view_override_template" type="Vendor\Module\Payment\Block\Info" />
</config>
```

2)Create Block:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Payment\Block;
 
class Info
{
    public function beforeToHtml(\Magento\Payment\Block\Info $subject)
    {        
            $subject->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::info/default.phtml');        
    }
}
```

3)Create Template file default.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @var \Magento\Payment\Block\Info $block
 * @see \Magento\Payment\Block\Info
 */
$specificInfo = $block->getSpecificInformation();
$title = $block->escapeHtml($block->getMethod()->getTitle());
?>
<dl class="payment-method">
    <dt class="title"><?= /* @noEscape */ $title ?></dt>
<?php if ($specificInfo) : ?>
    <dd class="content">
        <table class="data table">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @noEscape */ $title ?></caption>
            <?php foreach ($specificInfo as $label => $value) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml($label) ?></th>
                    <td>
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ nl2br($block->escapeHtml(implode("\n", $block->getValueAsArray($value, true)))) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
    </dd>
<?php endif;?>
</dl>
<?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
```

Comment: preference for="module_paympent_view_override_template" ?

Comment: yes you have to add preference

Comment: preference for // This should be class

Comment: yes the core block class you are extending for this

Comment: or you can also use plugin instead of preference

Answer (score 0):

try to preference block Magento\Payment\Block\Info.php

file di.xml

```
<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<config xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=""urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"">
    <preference for=""Magento\Payment\Block\Info"" type=""Vendor\Module\Block\Info"" />
</config>
```

on file Vendor\Module\Block\Info.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Info extends \Magento\Payment\Block\Info
{
.....................
    protected $_template = 'Vendor_Module::info/default.phtml';
....................
}
```

Finally, create your template